# Should the sentences containing "ever" always be in present perfect tense?

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs, present-perfect

I know that when we use "ever", the tense of verb is usually in present prefect tense: (check this [search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=ever%20present%20perfect&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8))

> Have you ever been in Iran?

But is it a rule? for example in the following sentence I wrote

> Sometimes I have simple ideas that can be useful. They could be obvious or not, or it is possible that no one ever has considered them as I done.

Could it be

> .... or is it possible that no one ever considered them as I did

Comment: Your revision is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Why do you say the verb is *usually in present prefect?*. I've no reason to suppose that's even *statistically* the case, let alone a "rule". It depends entirely on context. You might as well say we usually use the pronoun **I** in the present rather than past tense (where again, I've absolutely no idea whether that might be true or not, but it would be a worthless piece of information to learners, whichever way the statistics leaned).

Comment: Please check [this link](http://www.tolearnenglish.com/exercises/exercise-english-2/exercise-english-4147.php) or those in [this result](https://www.google.com/search?q=ever+present+perfect&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). Specially the first one says "ever" is used with "present perfect"

Comment: @FumbleFingers [this page](http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/present_perfect_tense06.html) is better place where it is said

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the point that page is making. I've no reason to question the idea that "time adverbs" are more likely to occur with present prefect constructions than with other tenses, or that of those time adverbs which *are* used in that way, ***ever, never, already, yet, still*** are probably the most common. That's not at all the same as saying that ***ever*** is ***usually*** used in present prefect tense, which I think is an unlikely assertion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't get the difference between *more likely to occur* and *usually occur*

Comment: Say for argument's sake there are ten different verb tenses and moods in English. If 20% of all usages involving ***ever*** feature present prefect, and the nine others all account for less than 10% each, it would be valid to say ***ever*** is more likely to occur with present prefect than with other forms. But that wouldn't mean constructions involving ***ever*** usually involve present perfect, since 80% of them *don't*. (Those figures are just by way of illustration - I've no idea of the actual values.)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context, the adverb ever can be used in the present, past, and future in questions, negative sentences, and sentences with if.  For examples:

.Have you ever been to Iran?

.Did you ever go to Iran?

.I don't think I'll ever go to Iran?

.If you are ever in London, come and see me.

. Do you ever play cricket.

You can also use ever after what, how, where, who to make a question more forceful such as "How ever can I thank you?".

I think the OP's sentence "Is it possible that no one ever considered them as I did?" is grammatically correct.

Comment: what means "did you ever go to Iran", to me it seems you ask someone about his past memories to know if he finally went to Iran or not, yes?

Comment: The sentence is in the past; the focus is on  the past. You are asking whether he went to Iran at any time in the past.

Comment: Also,  It's normal in AE to use ever with  the past simple, but the present perfect is also OK.  On the contrary, in BE,  you use ever with the present perfect, not in the past simple.